# Git push to repo's default branch

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-branch

I have a bash script that does the following:

1. Clones a repo;
2. Modifies some files;
3. Commits the changes;
4. Pushes the commits to repo's default branch.

Now, if I clone a repo with `git clone <repo>` I assume the default branch of the repo is cloned locally. If I push the commits with `git push`, is it 100% sure that the commits will be pushed to repo's default branch? I don't want to specify to which branch to push to (e.g.: `git push origin master`) because the script will be generic and repos will have various default branch names.

If some of my assumptions are wrong, please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the case, as of Git 1.8.3. You can easily test this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, git uses the branch called "master". So when you clone a repository, you will be in master branch. After doing changes, you can push your commits without declaring the branch name. Git pushes to the master branch of remote repository.

Comment: Doesn't git clone the _default_ branch on the repo? It could be named `master`, but if the default branch has some other name, wouldn't it clone that one? And for pushing, isn't this the same?

Comment: Even if the default branch has a different name, when you clone, you start to track that branch. So when you push your commits, you will send them to the default branch regardless of the branch name.

Comment: And is this happening 100% of the time? Or does it depend upon something?

Comment: Yes, for the default branch, that is happening. You can check `.git/config` file for the branch configuration to be sure.